# UIView frame size not updating in UITableViewCell (using Constraints)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

So I am aligning my collectionView inside my UITableViewCell, however once I launch the app it displays the width of my storyboard UITableViewCell instead of the actual iPad app itself (that changes once I start scrolling). Here is my current code

```
collectionView.frame.origin.x = collectionView.superview!.frame.width;
print(collectionView.superview!.frame.width)
```

The app prints this, it starts printing 728 once I start scrolling.

```
335.0
335.0
335.0
335.0
335.0
728.0
728.0
728.0
```

So my question is, why does this happen, and how can I make sure I always get the 728 width when aligning my collectionView?

Here are some images to help (the blue background is **collectionView**, the red background is **collectionView.superview**

[Image of my Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkpsO.png)

[Image of my app after launching it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEdNC.png)

[Image of my app after scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oeckh.png)

Comment: just call` layoutIfNeeded()` before accessing width.

Answer (score 0):

At first when you run

```
print(collectionView.superview!.frame.width)
```

it prints the storyboard encapuslated height  = 335 which is the iphone width you developed the layout with to access the right width inisde the vc's

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
 super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  // print here
}
```

or inside the cell

```
override func layoutSubviews()
 super.layoutSubviews()
  // print here
}
```

Comment: Hey I call this code above inside 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

How can I make it use the right layout size by default on there, so how do I call that method after it has laid out the subviews?